# Why is sharey = True ignored when adding facecolor?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The two subplots generated by the code below share a common y-axis. However, once I add `facecolor = "whitesmoke"` , the option `sharey = True` is ignored. It is as if I had specified `sharey = False`. Any idea how I can combine facecolor with sharey = True?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some example data to display
x1 = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y1 = np.sin(x1 ** 2)
y2 = np.sin(x2 ** 2) 
y2 = y2+1

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey = True)
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')
# ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax1 = plt.subplot(121, facecolor = "whitesmoke")
ax1 = plt.plot(x1,y1)
# ax2 = plt.subplot(122) 
ax2 = plt.subplot(122, facecolor = "whitesmoke") 
ax2 = plt.plot(x2,y2)
plt.
show()
```

[image: Figure with facecolor and sharey = True]

Comment: `plt.subplots(...)` creates two subplots.  With `ax1 = plt.subplot(121, ...)`. You create a new subplot at the same subplot at the same position as the already existing `ax1`.  You can replace `ax1 = plt.subplot(121, ...)` by `ax1.set_facecolor("whitesmoke")` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are witnessing does not have anything to do with `facecolor`. You are defining your figure and axes properly with `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)` but you overwrite your axes later by calling `ax1 = plt.subplot(121, facecolor = "whitesmoke")` and `ax2 = ...`. Your axes are not sharing the y-axis anymore because you deleted the ones that did.

`ax = plt.subplot(..., facecolor=...)` is not meant to add a facecolor to an existing ax, it's meant to add a subplot to the current figure. Use `ax.set_facecolor(...)` instead:

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some example data to display.
x1 = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y1 = np.sin(x1 ** 2)
y2 = np.sin(x2 ** 2) 
y2 = y2+1

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')
for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.set_facecolor("whitesmoke")
ax1.plot(x1, y1)
ax2.plot(x2, y2)
fig.show()
```